# selectize js use array as source

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, selectize.js

Hi I am getting back a JSON encoded array ("html") from my Ajax call that I would like to add in the selectize as both value and text (I am using a tag) . 
How can I do that ?

HTML

```
<input type="text" value="test" class="demo-default selectized" id="input-tags" tabindex="-1" style="display: block;">
```

JQUERY

```
try {
    data = $.parseJSON(html);
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(html);

outcome = (obj.outcome);

$('#input-tags').selectize({
            delimiter: ',',
            persist: false,
            maxItems: 1,
            create: function (input) {
                return {
                    value: input,
                    text: input
                }
            }
        });
```

}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could map the array onto an array of objects, like this:

```
data = $.parseJSON(html);
var items = data.map(function(x) { return { item: x }; });
```

Then use ["labelField" and "valueField"](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) to specify the text/value:

```
$('#input-tags').selectize({
        delimiter: ',',
        persist: false,
        options: items,
        labelField: "item",
        valueField: "item"
    });
```

[Fiddle Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ejVB7/3/)

Comment: FYI, you probably need to add `searchField: ['item'],` after that.

Answer (score 2):

With ES6 you can reduce your oneliner a bit

```
const items = data.map(item => ({item}));
```